# Reporting a User for Three Duplicate Accounts?

Tags: discussion, user-accounts

Should I report a user for having three duplicate accounts? And if so, how should I go about this?

On all three accounts, which are all clearly variations of the same quite specific name, the user has been posting the gamut of answers, ranging from incorrect or low quality answers that could be improved by some research to thinly veiled rants about the site.

I down-voted and/or flagged many, as well as attempted to make some constructive comments on why they were inappropriate according to the site's guidelines or not sufficient for an answer.

I am not trying to be a serial down-voter, but many of this user's "answers" are just plain bad and harmful to the site.

I have noticed that some of the user's comments and answers have since been deleted, which may mean that the problem is being resolved by moderators. However, I'm still concerned.

Is there any way to contact a mod privately to disclose the user's usernames, so that they can look into it further?

Comment: Marking as a duplicate somehow erased my previous comment. I posted it to state that I came to realize that this question was in fact a duplicate, to apologize for not searching more thoroughly beforehand, and to urge others to go upvote the original question.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Just flag any of the posts and explain the problem there. If we need more info, we have ways of contacting you privately.

The problem may have been dealt with already.

Comment: Indeed, I checked this morning and the accounts were deleted. I will keep this in mind if I ever encounter it again. Thanks.

Comment: I think it happened again. Why does this person keep getting deleted? have they caused any trouble? (curious, not arguing)

Comment: @marcellothearcane : The OP said "the user has been posting [amongst other things] ... thinly veiled rants about the site."  I'd expect the moderators to have reasonably thick skins on behalf of SE, but eventually, if the user is persistent and misusing the site, they are going to get deleted.