# How to Mark a Question as a Duplicate of Multiple Questions

Tags: discussion, flagging, vote-to-close, duplicates

This evening I came across [this question](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/405993/summarized-and-traveling-are-not-british-english).

In the comments, sumelic has indicated three potentially related questions. They are obviously better equipped than I to handle any duplicate closing in this case.

However, this got me wondering, how are posts that are duplicates of more than one question handled?

I've seen instances of questions that link to at least two duplicates on both ELU and ELU Meta; for example:

- [Changing usage of certain words](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/334179/changing-usage-of-certain-words)
- [How to handle questions with acceptable comments as answers but no answer itself?](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5090/how-to-handle-questions-with-acceptable-comments-as-answers-but-no-answer-itself)

So, my questions are:

1. How are multiple duplicate listings achieved?

   - Is it part of the close-vote process?
   - Does flagging influence it at all?
2. If I see a post that has been closed as a duplicate of a single question and notice that it also references another question, how should I go about notifying others about the additional duplicate? (e.g. a comment, a flag, a Meta post, etc.)

---

<sup>Hopefully my pre-ask search was more successful this time than for [one of my previous questions](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10650/reporting-a-user-for-three-duplicate-accounts)! As far as I could tell, this question has not yet been asked.</sup>

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. Users with gold tag badge having the privileges to single-handedly close as duplicates, and naturally, all moderators, [can edit the listed duplicates](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/291824/309993) once it's closed. It's a new feature actually. See the edit button in the image below:

[image: a link to edit the listed duplicates is shown]

2. Anything is fine. Meta post will get you attention from members who visit meta, and most meta visitors are experienced users with high-level privileges. Flagging for a moderator's attention would also work. Comments won't be noticeable if it gets buried under a dozen other comments. Also, the chances of a comment getting noticed are slim if the question hasn't been active recently.

Comment: Also you might want to mention that it happens when users vote to close as duplicate, but choose different duplicates.

Comment: @KitZ.Fox I'm not sure how that works. I can only close as a duplicate of one. And then edit the listed duplicate. Maybe I'm missing something.

Comment: Two different users choose one duplicate each, but they are different from each other.

Comment: @KitZ.Fox Ah, would you mind editing that in? I'd really appreciate that.